# My app got rejected on the App Store but I don't understand why

Tags: ios, app-store

I have submitted my app on the App Store and result I got this message saying:

> From Apple
> 4. 1 DESIGN: COPYCATS
> Design - 4.1

> Your app or its metadata appears to contain misleading content.

> Specifically, your app includes content that resembles  without the necessary authorization.

> Please see attached screenshots for details.

> Next Steps

> Please make the necessary changes to your app so that it does not infringe upon the rights of a third party:

> Remove all third-party marks from your app icon, screenshots, and previews.

Can someone explain to me how can I fix this issue or what's going on.

Comment: What is "المستشار عبدالله العقيل "?

Comment: you may need to remove عبدالله العقيل 's photo and references from your app or alternatively you could provide a proof of you have licence to use them to Apple.

Comment: then you need to include authorization from Abdullah Aqeel to include in your submission to Apple, because the image appears to be taken from the homepage of his website

Comment: @tom, عبدالله العقيل is a famous person ？

Comment: @aircraft yes he is and here is his website http://www.alaqeelabumostafa.com but i dont know what to do next to get the app approved. Russell said that i need to get authorization from him. will it be from him personally or the website or what exactly

Comment: So, is this resolved? What details you required to get app approved? Also, are Apple verified this authorised document (PDF) or after submitting the authorised letter (PDF) they are approving the app. Please share your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need an official document from the person concerned that you are creating the app on his behave. Ideally you present the app reviewer with an official letter (PDF) from the person, where he specifically mentions your name, app name and maybe also the purpose of the app. This should usually be enough for the reviewer.

Comment: So, is this resolved? What details you required to get app approved? Also, are Apple verified this authorised document (PDF) or after submitting the authorised letter (PDF) they are approving the app. Please share your comment.

Comment: So if there are multiple celebrities what will u do

Comment: You’ll need written permission from all people involved. As I’m not an Apple employee I cannot tell you much about the verification process.